# Magento - Show MSRP in cart

Tags: php, magento, cart

How do I show the msrp in cart in Magento 1.9? 
I guess the file is default.phtml, but

```
    $_price = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getMsrp()) ?>
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code works fine

```
<?php 
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); 
        echo $productType = $product->getmsrp();
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only gives me "0.00000".

Comment: Admin->Catalog->Manage product->Your Product->Product Infomation[ Price ] add Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price [ High as main price ]  and than after check ....

Comment: MSRP is set, I am able to display it in list.phtml and price.html - for some reason it does not work in cart

Comment: Go to chechout/cart.phtml and check there after thead tag

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php $_item = $this->getItem(); ?>
        <?php $_product = $_item->getProduct()->load(); ?>
        <?php $_product->getMsrp(); ?>
```

This did the trick for me.